# Creating a "crosstabs" style output

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a sample dataset:

```
id <- 1:100
gender <- sample(c('M','F'), 100, replace=TRUE)
age <- sample(18:22, 100, replace=TRUE)
ethnicity <- sample(c('W','B','H','A','O'), 100, replace = TRUE)
grade <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE)

df <- cbind(id,gender,age,ethnicity,grade) %>% as.data.frame()
```

My output I'm trying to achieve is as such:

```
+-------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Column Name | Value | A  | B  | C  | D  |
+-------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
| Gender      | F     | 15 | 11 | 17 | 10 |
| Gender      | M     |  9 | 17 | 14 |  7 |
| Age         | 18    |  4 |  6 |  5 |  4 |
| Age         | 19    |  3 |  6 |  4 |  3 |
| Age         | 20    |  5 |  6 |  7 |  3 |
| Age         | 21    |  7 |  7 |  5 |  4 |
| Age         | 22    |  5 |  3 | 10 |  3 |
| Ethnicity   | A     |  1 |  9 |  9 |  6 |
| Ethnicity   | B     |  7 |  8 |  5 |  2 |
| Ethnicity   | H     |  4 |  4 |  5 |  2 |
| Ethnicity   | O     |  6 |  4 |  5 |  4 |
| Ethnicity   | W     |  6 |  3 |  7 |  3 |
+-------------+-------+----+----+----+----+
```

So I'm **not** trying to create a row that say, combines the three categorical variables (Ex: "Hispanic Females Age 22 got 2 A's, 0 B's, 2 C's, etc..." I just want it broken out by the grade distribution by each gender, age, and ethnicity, but they're all in one column.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` we can get the data in long format, `count` occurrences of each `value` for each `grade` and get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
 select(-id) %>%
 pivot_longer(cols = -grade) %>%
 count(value, grade) %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = grade, values_from = n)


# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   value     A     B     C     D
#   <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 F         8    10    12    13
# 2 M        13    18    11    15
# 3 18        2     4     7     6
# 4 19        5     6     4     4
# 5 20        3     6     3     8
# 6 21        6     5     5     3
# 7 22        5     7     4     7
# 8 A         5     3     1     5
# 9 B         5     5     6     7
#10 H         1     4     3     3
#11 O         3    10     7     7
#12 W         7     6     6     6
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
id <- 1:100
gender <- sample(c('M','F'), 100, replace=TRUE)
age <- sample(18:22, 100, replace=TRUE)
ethnicity <- sample(c('W','B','H','A','O'), 100, replace = TRUE)
grade <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE)
df <- cbind(id,gender,age,ethnicity,grade) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Perfect! One more question: Is there a way I can choose the order of each row by column? Right now it goes Gender, Age, Ethnicity, right? What if I wanted it to go, say, Age, Ethnicity, Gender?

Comment: @gooponyagrinch select the order in `cols` argument of `pivot_longer`, Instead of `pivot_longer(cols = -grade)` use `...pivot_longer(cols = c(age, ethnicity, gender)) %>%...` or any order you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df[, -1]), id.var = 'grade'), value ~ grade, length)
#    value  A  B  C  D
# 1:    18  2  4  7  6
# 2:    19  5  6  4  4
# 3:    20  3  6  3  8
# 4:    21  6  5  5  3
# 5:    22  5  7  4  7
# 6:     A  5  3  1  5
# 7:     B  5  5  6  7
# 8:     F  8 10 12 13
# 9:     H  1  4  3  3
#10:     M 13 18 11 15
#11:     O  3 10  7  7
#12:     W  7  6  6  6
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
id <- 1:100
gender <- sample(c('M','F'), 100, replace=TRUE)
age <- sample(18:22, 100, replace=TRUE)
ethnicity <- sample(c('W','B','H','A','O'), 100, replace = TRUE)
grade <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 100, replace=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(id, gender, age, ethnicity, grade)
```